# ФОрзац чи форзАц?

Tags: наголос

Сьогодні знайома сказала, що правильно говорити фОрзац, а не форзАц. Шукала, але якісь різні варіанти вживання. Тож, як правиьно?

Comment: Вітаємо на Ukrainian Language.SE. Будь ласка, додайте до свого запитання що ви шукали і яких висновків ви вже дійшли. Почитайте про наші [критерії](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%96-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%96-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%96-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%96-good-questions-and-good-answers), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші питання. Ви завжди можете виправити своє питання або відповідь за допомогою посилання edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша знайома права. СУМ-11 дає таку інформацію:

> **ФО́РЗАЦ**, а, ч., спец. Подвійний аркуш паперу, що з’єднує книжку з
>   внутрішньою частиною обкладинки, а також служить для оформлення
>   книжки. В цій книжці [«Пісні братерства»] заслуговує похвали..
>   майстерно виконаний форзац із золотим лінійним рослинним орнаментом на
>   зеленому фоні (Укр. рад. граф., 1957, 119).

Отже, наголос на перший склад.